# Switching tabs in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I tried loading a php page in my webview.The php page has 3 tabs and the first tab is set to be active.But when i loaded the php page in my app through a webview , the first tab which is the active tab appears.

screenshot of the php page in the webview

[image]

But clicking on the rest of the tabs makes no change. The tabs work fine in my pc browser but not in my webview. Please help me.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you using JavaScript for the menu, because than you have to enable JavaScript in your webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your utilizing javascript, which is not enabled in `WebView`'s by default.

The following code is a quick example of how to enable javascript in a `WebView`:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```